# How to make LibGDX Invaders 3D Demo project to work?

Tags: 3d, project, libgdx, demo

After lots of struggle for importing jar files from nightly builds, I managed to get rid of initial errors after the invaders demo project import. No exlamation mark and no red cross marks on "gdx-invaders" and "gdx-invaders-android" projects. As there is no Desktop project included in this, cant test on desktop. Tried launching this on Android phone but got following error. "Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/badlogic/gdxinvaders/GdxInvadersAndroid;" 
"Link of class 'Lcom/badlogic/gdxinvaders/GdxInvadersAndroid;' failed"

Anyone knows how to resolve this?
As per the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19000556/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-when-running-libgdx-sample-gdx-invaders-for-deskt/19600420)

@Deen How to add gdx project in project tab? there are no gdx project as project. and couldnt find the following files - jpct_ae.jar and jpct_shaders.zip?

Any experts know how to resolve this please?

Answer (score 0):

Well rakesh there is no desktop project but you can run it on desktop through GdxInvadersDesktop in com.badlogic.gdxinvaders .  just run this file as java project to check it on desktop.

You dont need any - jpct_ae.jar and jpct_shaders.zip files for it so just forget these files.

I think you messed up the code while removing those initial  red cross marks . Simplest way to run these demos is to download the libgdx master and import all the files in eclipse. Then import invader game through demos . check for dependencies in these files. And thats it. You dont need to struggle for this :)